# Building maven project, doesn't include the web projects jar file

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have a multi-module maven project, and my web project's pom.xml file looks like:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>myapp-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myapp-web Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

This is a spring MVC application, and I have an embedded jetty instance also:

```
    Server server = new Server(8080);

    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
    webAppContext.setWar("file:/path/to/war/myapp-web.war"); 
    webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

I build the web project using maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

So what is confusing me is, when I unzipped the myapp.war file that maven produced during the build, I looked in the lib folder and I don't see the .jar file for the web project?

Also, how do I run embedded jetty with a .war file?

Comment: Are you referring to classes defined within your `myapp-web` project? Those get bundled into `WEB-INF/classes`, not a JAR in `WEB-INF/lib`. Building a WAR isn't particularly useful if you are going to be running the project with an embedded server, why not build a [superjar](http://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/)?

Comment: @Perception Why does Jetty have the .setWar() method then? I'm confused sorry.  If I build a superjar or uberjar (using maven shade?), then how will I use setWar() ?

Comment: disregard my previous comment, it was a generalization. More on topic, have you read [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/10/02/executable-wars-with-jetty/)

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the web project that ends up creating the war should go directly into WEB-INF/classes in the war, not into a jar file.

As long as you've set up your embedded Jetty correctly, you should be able to run the war using

```
java -jar myapp-web.war
```

The configuration would involve creating a main method, added the proper jetty dependencies, and specifying the main class when the manifest is generated.

The jetty-console-maven-plugin might be a simpler alternative for setting all of this up.  Take a look at this guide: http://www.dzone.com/links/r/make_your_war_file_executable_with_the_jetty_cons.html